# Migrating Local Folders from Thunderbird to Mail.app

Tags: macos, mac, mail.app

I am moving from Thunderbird to Mac mail on my iMac running OSX. If I uninstall Thunderbird will the local folders I created in Thunderbird remain on my computer for importing later?  I don't want to bring all of them over now, but would like to have the option of doing so at a later date.  I don't want to uninstall Tbird and then have the local folders disappear.

Comment: How will you uninstall Thunderbird?

Answer (score 1):

All your Thunderbird data, including the local mail data is stored in the [Profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird#Mac_OS_X), located either at `~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/<Profile name>/,` or "`~/Library/Application Support/Thunderbird/Profiles/<Profile name>/`.

Deleting the Thunderbird app won't delete any of the data there, unless you use a 3rd party uninstalled app like [AppZapper](http://appzapper.com/). You can of course make a manual backup of those folders for added safety.